# Android Getting a count of the visible children in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i'm trying to know how many items in recyclerview are visible for user, in some device this count is different and i cant't calculate that with below code:

```
private int countVisibleRow() {
    if (messagesView.getLayoutManager() != null) {
       LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) messagesView.getLayoutManager();
       int                 first         = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
       int                 last          = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
       return last - first;
    } else {
       return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you get as a result?

Comment: the whole concept of recyclerview is that you don't need to worry about how many are visible. The LayoutManager handles it accordingly for each device and may also cache some more rows. Why do you need the visible count?

Comment: @OrkunKoçyiğit i get zero

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy try my solution

Answer (score 0):

put your code inside onScroll listner method whenever you will scroll recylerView this method will be fire (put this code inside your Adapter class in constructor)

```
final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
        //Add this to your Recyclerview
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                //To check if  recycler last Visible Item
                int lastVisiblePos = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                int  firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: @shahis17june how about without scrolling items?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
public class LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller extends LinearLayoutManager {

    public LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller(Context context) {
        super(context, HORIZONTAL, false);
    }

    @Override
    public int findFirstVisibleItemPosition() {
        return super.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public int findLastVisibleItemPosition() {
        return super.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    }

    public LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state,
                                       int position) {
        RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new TopSnappedSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext());
        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
    }

    private class TopSnappedSmoothScroller extends LinearSmoothScroller {
        public TopSnappedSmoothScroller(Context context) {
            super(context);

        }

        @Override
        public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
            return LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller.this
                    .computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
        }

        @Override
        protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
            return SNAP_TO_START;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like below:

```
   layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller(QuestionsActivity.this);
  paginationRV.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
```

Comment: so how can i get count of items when they are visible for user?

Comment: using same as you get layoutmanger.findLastVisibleItemPosition()

Comment: but make sure layoutmanager is instance of LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller class

Comment: by default i have two visible item on recyclerView but i get `-1` always

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy what you get in  layoutmanger.findLastVisibleItemPosition()

Comment: i get `-1` always

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy this method you have to call after data load into recyclerview. else its give -1 both

Comment: Takkar  yes, i know that